# ASA IPSec tunnel up, but logging errors?

Tags: cisco-asa, ipsec

I am getting the following errors on an ASA;

```
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-714003: IP = 1.2.3.4, IKE Responder starting QM: msg id = 5293ff7c
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713236: IP = 1.2.3.4, IKE_DECODE RECEIVED Message (msgid=5293ff7c) with payloads : HDR + HASH (8) + SA (1) + NONCE (10) + KE (4) + ID (5) + ID (5) + NONE (0) total length : 292
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-715047: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, processing hash payload
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-715047: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, processing SA payload
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-715047: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, processing nonce payload
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-715047: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, processing ke payload
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713906: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, processing ISA_KE for PFS in phase 2
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-715047: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, processing ID payload
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-714011: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, ID_IPV4_ADDR ID received 1.2.3.444
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713025: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, Received remote Proxy Host data in ID Payload:  Address 1.2.3.444, Protocol 0, Port 0
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-715047: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, processing ID payload
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-714011: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, ID_IPV4_ADDR ID received
5.6.7.8
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713024: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, Received local Proxy Host data in ID Payload:  Address 5.6.7.8, Protocol 0, Port 0
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713906: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, QM IsRekeyed old sa not found by addr
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713221: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, Static Crypto Map check, checking map = outside_map, seq = 10...
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713222: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, Static Crypto Map check, map = outside_map, seq = 10, ACL does not match proxy IDs src:1.2.3.444 dst:5.6.7.8
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713066: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, IKE Remote Peer configured for crypto map: outside_dyn_map
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-715047: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, processing IPSec SA payload
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-5-713904: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, All IPSec SA proposals found unacceptable!
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713906: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, sending notify message
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-715046: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, constructing blank hash payload
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713906: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, constructing ipsec notify payload for msg id 5293ff7c
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-715046: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, constructing qm hash payload
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713236: IP = 1.2.3.4, IKE_DECODE SENDING Message (msgid=c34f6ff7) with payloads : HDR + HASH (8) + NOTIFY (11) + NONE (0) total length : 84
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-3-713902: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, QM FSM error (P2 struct &0xca9c89b0, mess id 0x5293ff7c)!
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-715065: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, IKE QM Responder FSM error history (struct &0xca9c89b0)  <state>, <event>:  QM_DONE, EV_ERROR-->QM_BLD_MSG2, EV_NEGO_SA-->QM_BLD_MSG2, EV_IS_REKEY-->QM_BLD_MSG2, EV_CONFIRM_SA-->QM_BLD_MSG2, EV_PROC_MSG-->QM_BLD_MSG2, EV_HASH_OK-->QM_BLD_MSG2, NullEvent-->QM_BLD_MSG2, EV_COMP_HASH
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713906: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, sending delete/delete with reason message
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-3-713902: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, Removing peer from correlator table failed, no match!
```

I only have access to this end, and I don't have access to the local LAN IP it terminates on.

Speaking to the remote end operator, he can connect over the tunnel to the local LAN IP so it is working, but I am still seeing errors in the logs, in particular "All IPSec SA proposals found unacceptable!".

Via `show isakmp sa detail` the peer is active and under `show ipsec sa detail` I can see the packet counters for encapsulated and dencapsulated packets going up.

How is it this is working? Should I be worried about the logs?

Comment: What's your configuration look like?  It's failing to find a static peer and falling back to the dynamic peer - that's not generally what you want to see on a site to site connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem know. I think I needed another set of eyes to point it out to me so thanks for that.

```
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713222: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, Static Crypto Map check, map = outside_map, seq = 10, ACL does not match proxy IDs src:1.2.3.444 dst:5.6.7.8
Jan 24 2012 17:15:13 ASA1 : %ASA-7-713066: Group = 1.2.3.4, IP = 1.2.3.4, IKE Remote Peer configured for crypto map: outside_dyn_map
```

These lines say it all. outside_map has the remote end point peer IP defined, but it should be their proxy IP.

Thanks for the push ;)